# Continuative てform of adjective and noun

Tags: grammar

> 「……む、なんか匂う。この**甘酸っぱくて雨上がり**、給料日に隠したまま思い出せなくなった一万円のような気配は、間違いなく秘密の匂い」

My TL:
Something smells. This swith smell after the rain.  A presence like a 10000 yen bill you hid on paycheck day and became unable to recall it. I am certain, the smell of a secret.

Shouldn't it be

雨上がりの甘酸っぱい.....

Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic structure is comprised of 気配 modified with three modifiers of (1) この, (2) 甘酸っぱい and (3) 雨上がり、給料日に…思い出せなくなった一万円のような.

甘酸っぱい is enough as it is, but it's interfered with another clause and somehow changed to the te form.

It may look strange that 雨上がり is used adverbially here, but using に would feel clumsy since there's another に as in 給料日に. In addition, analogy to adverbs that represent time kind of makes it sound natural.

Comment: I see, 雨上がり is used as a temporal adverb. Any kind of temporal noun can used as an adverb?

Comment: きのう、きょう、あした are the kind. At least, 雨上がり is not a kind that's usually used adverbially.